# Divide HTML into pages based on content size

Tags: css, html

I am creating a webapp to edit documents. Each document can have multiple pages. Each page has a fixed size (I am using the standard papersize in Germany which is DIN A4 and has 210mm width x 297mm height). Therefore I set the the body size of my HTML appropriately.

The document already looks nice and they way I want it to be. There is only one major problem I want the webpage to devide my content automatically into pages (eg. `div` boxes) that have the size of a DIN A4 (as I mentioned above).

How can I do this? It would be nice if there is a solution that is CSS only, but JavaScript also works. I created a CodePen for you to understand my problem: [example codepen](http://codepen.io/wonderbummer/pen/qiIpx)

I want the behaviour like Google Drive (Text Documents) which creates a new page when one page of the document is full. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Google Drive Example]

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>This is the title of the document</h1><b>Table of contents</b>
    <ol>
      <li>Das Programm</li>
      <li>Hintergründe</li>
      <li>Vision</li>
    </ol>
    <p>some random text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font: 15px arial;
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 25mm 15mm 20mm 35mm;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
ol {
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: The simple answer to this is: You don't. HTML/CSS is not really designed for this. There is probably a solution for this, but I can guarantee, that you will get very frustrated, because there will be many pitfalls on the way. You may want to look into alternative techniques such as PDF for this.

Comment: You can do this. Google Drive also does it, but I don't know how.

Comment: Google Drive does what exactly? Do you mean when it displays a document page by page? That is something that happens server-side by converting a **PDF** (or similar document format).

Comment: When you edit a Text Document in Google Drive (their "word" software) it creates a page when one page of the document is full. Take a look at this [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mvg90idia6tp7qb/drive%20pages.PNG). I edited the question to display the screenshot.

Comment: Is that a new literal html (different url etc) from google drive or is it just a visual container. Printing separate pages would be handled by a print style sheet. Generally trying to apply print principles to web pages is folly. They are two very different mediums.

Comment: @wonderbummer They are using tricks there. It's not flowing HTML content they are displaying, but absolutely positioned elements simulating a word processor and its document structure. Again: This works with PDF and similar word processor-like documents, but not with arbitrary HTML/CSS.

Comment: @RoToRa I will try to simulate this behaviour by using JavaScript. I will post it here when I make progress.

Comment: You are going to need a JS script that takes the last word filling the canvas and continue on the next page as long as there is text left.
There's no way to do it with only CSS.

Answer (score -1):

as far as i think you can't divide the page into different pages but you can make the whole document scrollable i mean you add `overflow:auto` in your css after defining the the height and width of the div containing document

```
#document_carrier{
    width:500px;
        height:350px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    overflow:auto;

}
```

you can have your height and width as according to your needs....
actually me upload button is just to show you you to make the page scrollable but you can add other javascript functions or other language function to upload file.

js fiddle [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bEC54/)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a solution for my problem. I want to have multiple pages which I can print out if I need to.